# Any way of pulling release notes in circleci

Tags: github, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

Is there any way of pulling release notes associated with a certain tag when building with circleci ?

During the checkout step circleci clones the github repository along with tags and other meta-data.

My requirement is that if any tag has a release attached to it it should pull the release notes with it also ?

Is there any configuration available in circleci/github to achieve this ?

My circleci build initiates when I create a release on github with release message. Creating release on github implicitly creates a tag on a particular commit/branch. When the build initiates on circleci it automatically fetches the tag. I want a way to configure circleci to fetch the associated release notes if any for a particular tag.

Comment: Where are your release notes stored?

Comment: My circleci build initiates when I create a release on github with release message.
Creating release on github implicitly creates a tag on a particular commit/branch.

When the build initiates on circleci it automatically fetches the tag. I want a way to configure circleci to fetch the associated release notes if any for a particular tag.

Comment: The [github project/release API endpoints documention](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) looks like a good read.